# In Insanely Twisted Shadow Planet is there any way to return to the home world?

Tags: insanely-twisted-planet

I'm attempting 100% completion and it looks like I missed a piece of artwork on the home world. Is there any way to return to the home world to collect it? If not, does the game have any new game plus type functionality to allow me to carry anything over between plays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way to return to the home world. I think videos and concept art carry over if you start a new game, though I don't think the actual collectibles do.